# How to add nginx on already existing apache 2.2 SSL, centos

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, centos

I want to include nginx over Apache, but my apache is already using certbot SSL certificate and listens to port 443, how to include nginx in it?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is use nginx as reverse proxy to apache.
By this, you can use apache to listen on port 80, and setup let's encrypt on nginx, so the ssl traffic will be handled by nginx.

Have a look some docs on [Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

Comment: Thanks. People suggested to me that it's not a good combo and I should move to nginx only which I did.